Is that a bad idea to include `version` in the `package.json` of an application?
I am learning NuxtJS and try to build a new project myself to write some code.
It was quite smooth to set everything up, until I tried to add a version number to package.json.
2 warnings are given (Although I think it can be ignored.):
 WARN  [nuxt] Expected @nuxt/kit to be at least 3.12.2 but got 1.0.0. This might lead to unexpected behavior. Check your package.json or refresh your lockfile.

 WARN  [nuxt] Expected @nuxt/schema to be at least 3.12.2 but got 1.0.0. This might lead to unexpected behavior. Check your package.json or refresh your lockfile.    

Here is my package.json
{
  "name": "nuxt3-starter",
  "private": true,
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "dev": "nuxt dev",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "preview": "nuxt preview",
    "postinstall": "nuxt prepare",
    "nuxt": "nuxt",
    "module": "nuxt module",
    "postmodule": "eslint ./nuxt.config.ts --fix",
    "lint:check": "eslint . --cache",
    "lint": "eslint . --cache --fix"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nuxt/eslint": "^0.3.13",
    "@nuxt/icon": "1.0.0-rc.1",
    "@nuxt/image": "^1.7.0",
    "@nuxtjs/seo": "2.0.0-rc.10",
    "@opentelemetry/api": "1.8.0",
    "@pinia/nuxt": "^0.5.1",
    "nuxt": "^3.12.2",
    "nuxt-typed-router": "^3.6.4",
    "primevue": "4.0.0-rc.2",
    "vue": "^3.4.29",
    "vue-router": "^4.3.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@primevue/nuxt-module": "4.0.0-rc.2",
    "@vueuse/core": "^10.11.0",
    "@vueuse/nuxt": "^10.11.0",
    "eslint": "^8.56.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^9.26.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vuejs-accessibility": "^2.3.0",
    "lint-staged": "^15.2.7",
    "sass": "^1.77.6",
    "simple-git-hooks": "^2.11.1"
  },
  "simple-git-hooks": {
    "pre-commit": "npx lint-staged"
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "*.{cjs,mjs,js,ts,tsx,vue}": [
      "eslint --cache --fix"
    ]
  }
}

I tried to remove the version from package.json and the warnings are gone.
So, is that actually a bad idea to add a version number to the package.json in a nuxt apllication?

That's really weird. I'd start by checking the Nuxt issues list for similar reports or submit a new one

It's something to do with the workspace:* value they set for dependency versions. I'd definitely be raising it as a bug

That aside, unless you're publishing your project as an NPM package, you really don't need to set the version field

I also think it is a bit weird as well and I was also wondering if version is really needed in my project if I am not going to publish it. Thanks for the explanation!

Did you try to specify the 3.12.2 version ? "version": "3.12.2"

@Jean-Loup This certainly solves the problem, where @nuxt/kit is set to workspace:*. But as a new created project, I would not want to start the version from 3.12.2. There will also be problems if I raise the version later.

And as per the suggestion from @Phil, I am omitting it now, where I really do not need to publish it lol
